# Supervised ranking algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, recommender-system, ranking

I'm working on a problem statement which involves ranking some short-lived items in an order such that the items expected to sell the most in the next n days are ranked on top - basically ranking based on expected sales.

I've labelled historical data for such items. The data includes information about the items themselves - item metadata, sales trends for the item, user affinity towards the item, etc. along with the ideal ranks for different items on any given day. The ideal ranks are obtained by converting sales data in the next n days and sorting them to get ranks.

My question is are there any supervised ranking algorithms that expect day-wise and listwise candidate metadata and rank as input? I've come across adarank but from what I understand that is more tailored for information retrieval systems than for ranking problems.

One approach I can think of is fitting a regression algorithm to the sales data directly and then computing ranks at inference time by sorting based on the predicted output.